# If in $\Delta PQR$, $\angle P=120^\circ$, $PS\perp QR$ at $S$ and $PQ+QS=SR$, then the measure of $\angle Q$ is

Tags: geometry

If in $\Delta PQR$, $\angle P=120^\circ$, $PS\perp QR$ at $S$ and $PQ+QS=SR$, then the measure of $\angle Q$ is:

(a) $20^\circ$

(b) $50^\circ$

(c) $40^\circ$

(d) $30^\circ$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Urgent requests for problems where you show no work of your own are likely to get votes to close and downvotes rather than answers. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Reflect $R$ across $S$, you get new point $T$ on line $Q-S-R$ such that $TQ = QP$.

So if $\angle Q = 2x$ then $$\angle QTP =  \angle TPQ =  \angle PRT = x$$ Then we have $$ 3x+120^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}\implies x = 20^{\circ}$$

So the answer is $40^{\circ}$.

[image]

Comment: Hello sir, can you show with the figure please.

Comment: You can draw it your self. Can't you?

Comment: I am not getting TQ = QP.

Comment: Please sir, send the figure

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if it was usefull to you